Node modules changings are not reflected in react vite
I'm changing a specific part from a node_module adding an extra if
  console.log("in hell")
  if(!id.includes("protected")){
    this.props.actions.removeLane({
      laneId: id
    });
  }

The problem is that the breakpoint hit this part of code, showing the correct values, but the changings are not reflected in project for example this console.log doesnt show anything in console, I tried to clean npm cache, and restart vscode, but this the issue remains (I'm not updating npm or installing anything, I'll remove this module from git ignore)
